# Can a Quine-Rosser ordered pair be a coordinate of itself?

Tags: set-theory

Given a set $x$ and a Quine-Rosser ordered pair $p\ne\emptyset$, is it possible to have $p=(p,x)$ or $p=(x,p)$?
I am working in the context of ZFC to be clear.
I'm asking this because with this definition of ordered pairs there is, in general, no membership chain linking $a$ or $b$ to $(a,b)$.

I tried to do a proof by contradiction, but didn't manage to find any. In fact, I tried to prove that
$p=(p,p)$ leads to a contradiction, and realised just moments ago that this is not the most general case
anyway, so in the end I spent quite some time trying to prove the wrong thing.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Comment: Assuming that you follow the definition on wikipedia, let $p$ be any set such that no element of $p$ contains a natural number. Then you can see that $p = (p, \emptyset)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the sets $p = \{ \{n\} \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ and $q = \{ \emptyset \}$.

We have $\varphi[p] = \{ \varphi(x) \:|\: x \in p \} = \{ \varphi(\{n\}) \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{ \sigma[\{n\}] \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \} = \{ \{n + 1\} \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \} $.

We have $\psi[q] = \{ \psi(\emptyset) \} = \{ \{0\}\}$.

Therefore, $(p,q) = \varphi[p]\: \cup \psi[q] = \{ \{n + 1\} \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \} \:\cup\: \{ \{ 0 \} \} = \{ \{n\} \:|\: n \in \mathbb{N} \} = p$.

Comment: Well, that was way simpler than I thought. Thanks.